# Append the suffix to predecessor element if all its following elements have the suffix in them

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to, move(remove from item and append to group) suffix if ALL the tr(item) in that group have that suffix in their td(index=1) element's value. That means  '[s2]' should be move to Group A and [s1] to Group B

**This XML should be:**

```
<table xmlns="MyNamespaceUri"> 
  <tr type="group"> <td index="1">Group A</td> </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type A1 [s1],[s2],[s3]</td> 
    <td index="2">11</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type A2 [s1],[s2]</td> 
    <td index="2">21</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type A3 [s2],[s4]</td> 
    <td index="2">31</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="total"> <td index="2">63</td> </tr> 

  <tr type="group"> 
    <td index="1">Group B</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type B1 [s1],[s2],[s3]</td> 
    <td index="2">12</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type B2 [s1],[s3]</td> 
    <td index="2">22</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type B3 [s1],[s4]</td> 
    <td index="2">32</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="total"> <td index="2">66</td> </tr> 
</table>
```

**Transformed like this:**

```
<table xmlns="MyNamespaceUri"> 
  <tr type="group"> <td index="1">Group A [s2]</td> </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type A1 [s1],[s3]</td> 
    <td index="2">11</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type A2 [s1]</td> 
    <td index="2">21</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type A3 [s4]</td> 
    <td index="2">31</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="total"> <td index="2">63</td> </tr> 

  <tr type="group"> 
    <td index="1">Group B [s1]</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type B1 [s2],[s3]</td> 
    <td index="2">12</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type B2 [s3]</td> 
    <td index="2">22</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="item"> 
    <td index="1"> Item Type B3 [s4]</td> 
    <td index="2">32</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr type="total"> <td index="2">66</td> </tr> 
</table>
```

Thanks a ton in advance.

EDIT:

Being a newbie to XSL/T, here's what I have after working for a couple of days on this. I couldn't get 'replace' function to work; was throwing up a function not found or valid exception (though I changed to version 2.0); then tried translate (which is not appropriate for this problem).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="MyNamespaceUri" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* "/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="arg1" select="'[s2]'"></xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="a:table/a:tr[@type='group']/a:td">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="arg2" select="../../a:tr[@type='item']/a:td[@index='1']"></xsl:variable>
    <td>
      <xsl:if test="contains($arg2,$arg1)='true'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$arg1" />
      </xsl:if>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:tr[@type='item']/a:td[@index='1']">
    <td index="1">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $arg1, '')" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:table/a:tr[@type='group']/a:td"/>
```

Comment: People are far more likely to help you if you show them that you've put some effort or research into the task at hand before asking the question - we're here to help, but we're not here to do it for you

Comment: Question shows absolutely no research nor attempt at anything.

Comment: I have included what I have so far and couldn't proceed any further

Answer (score 0):

The biggest challenge you have is the input xml structure, which is the only challenge I'm going to address (i.e. the rest is up to you). Really what you have is a table with 10 rows but you need to group subsets of those rows together such that you can isolate the rows which *belong* to group A and the rows which *belong* to group b. It's difficult to come up with `XPath`s that can do that but it's not impossible.

For instance, this template isolates a `tr` group's item's in a variable and then copy's the variable:

```
<xsl:template match="a:table/a:tr[@type='group']">
    <xsl:variable name="trs" select="following-sibling::a:tr[ . &lt;&lt; current()/following-sibling::a:tr[@type='total'][1]]" />

    <xsl:copy-of select="$trs" />
</xsl:template>
```

The key is the XPath `following-sibling::a:tr[ . &lt;&lt; current()/following-sibling::a:tr[@type='total'][1]]` - this means "select all of my following siblings nodes which are `tr`s up until the first occurrence of a `tr` which is of `type='total'`

Since you now have the ability to isolate the `item` rows into their own variable, you can now go ahead an write the code which tests the contents of the variable's `td/text()` values for the presence of matching `String` and add conditional logic as appropriate.

Your code also has some namespace issues. When you're copying, ensure that you don't lose the input's namespace along the way - note `copy-namespaces="yes"`:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="yes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```